# Exim wrongly resolve the host that authenticates via smtp, when sending outgoing mail from PHP and my server's domains?

Tags: smtp, email-server, dovecot, exim

I have a server with WHM and Cpanel in OVH Canada with a main ip +4 additional ipv4, 2 of which are assigned to their corresponding domain and 2 are unused:
suppose the ips are:

```
144.217.55.5 (main)

167.114.80.108 (empty)
167.114.80.109 (domain1.com)
167.114.80.110 (domain2.com)   <-----
167.114.80.111 (empty)
```

When I use PHP to send emails, I connect via SMTP with the following conf

```
host: mail.domain2.com   <----
port: 465
encryption: SSL
username: xxxxxx
pass: xxxxxx
```

The problem comes when I see the exim logs:

```
2020-09-04 11:09:26 1kECP8-0002Ze-4L <= admin@dominio2.com H=(www.dominio2.com) [167.114.80.109]:43018 P=esmtpsa X=TLS1:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:128 CV=no A=dovecot_login:info@dominio2.com S=130398 id=d6243cac0e818469706920622447795b@www.dominio2.com T="Example email" for example@hotmail.com
2020-09-04 11:09:26 1kECP8-0002Ze-4L Sender identification U=linux_username D=dominio2.com S=info@dominio2.com
2020-09-04 11:09:26 1kECP8-0002Ze-4L SMTP connection outbound 1599228566 1kECP8-0002Ze-4L dominio2.com example@hotmail.com
2020-09-04 11:09:28 1kECP8-0002Ze-4L => example@hotmail.com R=dkim_lookuphost T=dkim_remote_smtp H=hotmail-com.olc.protection.outlook.com [104.47.18.97] X=TLS1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:256 CV=yes C="250 2.6.0 <d6243cac0e818469706920622447795b@www.dominio2.com> [InternalId=34888019366026, Hostname=AM6EUR05HT076.eop-eur05.prod.protection.outlook.com] 141834 bytes in 0.308, 449.544 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery -> 250 2.1.5"
2020-09-04 11:09:28 1kECP8-0002Ze-4L Completed
```

As you can see in the log, "domain2.com" does not resolve to the correct IP (.110) but ... but to a wrong one (.109),
This ends in a header received in outlook like this:

```
-----------------------------------
Recibed E-Mail in Outlook (Headers)
-----------------------------------

Received: from AM7EUR06HT132.eop-eur06.prod.protection.outlook.com
(2603:10b6:208:23c::30) by MN2PR10MB4317.namprd10.prod.outlook.com with HTTPS
via MN2PR18CA0025.NAMPRD18.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM; Fri, 4 Sep 2020 16:01:34 +0000
Received: from AM7EUR06FT032.eop-eur06.prod.protection.outlook.com
(2a01:111:e400:fc36::46) by
AM7EUR06HT132.eop-eur06.prod.protection.outlook.com (2a01:111:e400:fc36::155)
with Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2,
cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id 15.20.3348.16; Fri, 4 Sep
2020 16:01:34 +0000
Authentication-Results: spf=pass (sender IP is 167.114.80.110)
smtp.mailfrom=dominio2.com; hotmail.com; dkim=pass (signature was verified)
header.d=dominio2.com;hotmail.com; dmarc=pass action=none
header.from=dominio2.com;compauth=pass reason=100
Received-SPF: Pass (protection.outlook.com: domain of dominio2.com
designates 167.114.80.110 as permitted sender)
receiver=protection.outlook.com; client-ip=167.114.80.110;
helo=dominio2.com;
Received: from dominio2.com (167.114.80.110) by
AM7EUR06FT032.mail.protection.outlook.com (10.233.255.87) with Microsoft SMTP
Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id
15.20.3348.16 via Frontend Transport; Fri, 4 Sep 2020 16:01:33 +0000
X-IncomingTopHeaderMarker:
OriginalChecksum:31ABEA364637255ED65C68929672F5F172ABBF7E27E44C1C7A5ACCD2A2B9CA55;UpperCasedChecksum:0D6163CB071A5666BD244BDF2B638F4D148911D1AAE91E91B8C288BE8DC77B71;SizeAsReceived:1958;Count:19
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed;
d=dominio2.com; s=default; h=Content-Type:MIME-Version:To:From:Subject:Date
:Message-ID:Sender:Reply-To:Cc:Content-Transfer-Encoding:Content-ID:
Content-Description:Resent-Date:Resent-From:Resent-Sender:Resent-To:Resent-Cc
:Resent-Message-ID:In-Reply-To:References:List-Id:List-Help:List-Unsubscribe:
List-Subscribe:List-Post:List-Owner:List-Archive;
bh=opwt3wnDE58VuNQ/uDJaZEwEYa6UoNjUOntsZNqxkX8=; b=kdpDW7TQQW/dH1DndZWOsyQqxU
iDhzG5VA+Xm2qahk36UfJNIRxp2FY+0gP7ArUAiBssVATccuuJzRkNHz4+8zJ/xELhprnDUg6sQZx
Ymb7QvBSSY5THoVAncADnwEuGF+AhFwti0+7F3ZOrpW57/pqF46AEIZSag8keGiH8fbCuMnoUzdFk
FWYgXYAsHdG5Pe31heksKHca7cJCf/DX1tdDu7pfE35F6vQTDJfBVoZk8ZF/u1TtVpya0BKDuo+hx
2OgGFvm9gyf+Dr9czpgL3qiUK9c5oM1X2HnRNca3/vcaKFgVVQx3tpULmwCM3MIyiTxwCYl1Rv+hJ
T0I3z3qQ==;
Received: from [167.114.80.109] (port=53560 helo=www.dominio2.com)
by server.myprimaryserver.com with esmtpa (Exim 4.93)
(envelope-from <info@dominio2.com>)
id 1kEE9c-0004Dx-Kb
for example@hotmail.com; Fri, 04 Sep 2020 13:01:32 -0300
Message-ID: <91de5533b34ed6dafd30fc1791ed5fbf@www.dominio2.com>
Date: Fri, 04 Sep 2020 13:01:32 -0300
Subject: [MyWebSite] Recuperar su =?utf-8?Q?contrase=C3=B1a?=
From: MyWebMail - domain2.com <info@dominio2.com>
To: example@hotmail.com
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
boundary="_=_swift_v4_1599235292_7fddbc54cfbf1e9b40d7f7974bdfb7a8_=_"
X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - server.myprimaryserver.com
X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - hotmail.com
X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [47 12] / [47 12]
X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - dominio2.com
X-Get-Message-Sender-Via: server.myprimaryserver.com: authenticated_id: info@dominio2.com
X-Authenticated-Sender: server.myprimaryserver.com: info@dominio2.com
X-Source:
X-Source-Args:
X-Source-Dir:
X-IncomingHeaderCount: 19
Return-Path: info@dominio2.com
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationStartTime: 04 Sep 2020 16:01:33.6996
(UTC)
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationStartTimeReason: OriginalSubmit
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationInterval: 1:00:00:00.0000000
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationIntervalReason: OriginalSubmit
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Network-Message-Id:
efc4d144-0da7-407b-2f5a-08d850ebcba4
X-EOPAttributedMessage: 0
X-EOPTenantAttributedMessage: 84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa:0
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-MessageDirectionality: Incoming
X-MS-PublicTrafficType: Email
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource:
AM7EUR06FT032.eop-eur06.prod.protection.outlook.com
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Anonymous
X-MS-UserLastLogonTime: 9/4/2020 3:58:04 PM
X-MS-Office365-Filtering-Correlation-Id: efc4d144-0da7-407b-2f5a-08d850ebcba4
X-MS-TrafficTypeDiagnostic: AM7EUR06HT132:
X-MS-Exchange-EOPDirect: true
X-Sender-IP: 167.114.80.110
X-SID-PRA: INFO@dominio2.com
X-SID-Result: PASS
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-PCL: 2
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: 0
X-Microsoft-Antispam: BCL:0;
X-OriginatorOrg: outlook.com
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-OriginalArrivalTime: 04 Sep 2020 16:01:33.5947
(UTC)
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Network-Message-Id: efc4d144-0da7-407b-2f5a-08d850ebcba4
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Id: 84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-AuthSource:
AM7EUR06FT032.eop-eur06.prod.protection.outlook.com
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-AuthAs: Anonymous
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-FromEntityHeader: Internet
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-RMS-PersistedConsumerOrg:
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStamped: AM7EUR06HT132
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-EndToEndLatency: 00:00:01.2929062
X-MS-Exchange-Processed-By-BccFoldering: 15.20.3348.016
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery:
abwl:1;rwl:0;ucf:0;jmr:0;ex:0;auth:1;dest:I;OFR:SenderInAddressBook;ENG:(5062000282)(90000117)(90011020)(91015020)(91040095)(9000001)(9005001)(9020002)(9050020)(9060021)(9100082)(5061607266)(5061608174)(4900115)(2008001094)(2008000094)(4920090)(6400023)(4950131)(560107);
X-Message-Info:
ikU7DQaERA5q4jCCF/ZwqeSEZ9VGkJDl0GWtPIijDWAFCIyIG8Uo70QBHFDDqbHy0F9NQVZQE2/4qEVhvCQ3mkg0I/ZWkgmSVFgGjpbZLEQX5zwBrYcwvHIlUSoWBErWim40CqFUGADVZG/cU9fUHBMnqkOwvKOYIsGRaUdLCG8K10rGFTlibv5SgI7+CY4a2VPDO727vgqOTanpuGjLRDHXWhbTJbFI8GO+zrbfvnu8VXQfmlLO5lUc0NempIteIlVG8Xr5mrySzqu1Mb5w3ewTt3VWxJ5CeBu0cuTVpi8LS4cKvKLAIBA7BVjWTMvC/mnEgZ5q9gpEfveHdYns7z3yfEu7fy+r3yMxozgs8YLSePRF7PLtHJezC2ebZwwIi17C4LtMeyQ57XsoJaS+PmdWnI7lUFxX0/qmvGVYTzuQ2szUguLkpYNGaea2FzXA
X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTA7YT0xO0Q9MTtHRD0xO1NDTD0tMQ==
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Message-Info:
=?utf-8?B?QlJ3bFRkVWhoeXJ4bkhkdXhVdFliV1Fkbkk0NkVQVFYzbG9ZZVhrZUhpVjNp?=
=?utf-8?B?SGVpYVVxb0k0NU56RXZNNEZyWmU0anNKVlkyZ3pKMmtsWENjR3hlZUt4OG1L?=
=?utf-8?B?NytFQlF5eHhIcmQyRnpHeHkySWkwMENFTUp5ajZ4M1E1bm9DM0g0S0p5ZnVX?=
=?utf-8?B?WFlSNXoxN1FvcEpXMXF0bVAwdWY4a2c5U2RYa0tkSS9KcmRGczQ3UXhaTEND?=
=?utf-8?B?Zld0eXh1blZGb21rdDVSTVVQbU1RTk5oc0o4Y1BVU3V5NzlLQmJUL3FJZDNJ?=
=?utf-8?B?bFNKbXpNYmF4VW94L0hoYThsbHA2blpITGVSRHc5YzhXV2lzOUFzM3JtRUM0?=
=?utf-8?B?dXp0THVNUUdjbjJFK1UrZVFXQWM1YUNmaUNsbFpIeldTRDcxbkNPSFMxZ25H?=
=?utf-8?B?MGtCYnR5NTZ6dXA3MC9hbGhKUnN1OThqZy9FaXNoK1NpQ3ljUzBnQk5YTWNY?=
=?utf-8?B?dmRCWXpUZkY3NXY4NzloZkgvd2YxT0I3ZHlBejZ1S3NHMEUvTHd1RFptY3NU?=
=?utf-8?B?bm1qZ0g0OTJpSVJNamJ2dE5BMTIrTWJGRVlORzJxN0NjUnp2enZjWGhDV0Ir?=
=?utf-8?B?YmxUY3FHVjJ4VUVEYVpORmh6alFXSXViSllRL2VjYlJsMDh6TCtlYjkxR1Rj?=
=?utf-8?B?NGxXRUVUS1NQTWo4eTdRK0JlT29hQnJVTUN1MkhzVTR5YXZNY3ZPcjJtSDZZ?=
=?utf-8?B?QUdKbFV5bEQwb0xBSGRFaGJ2NnVhTnJMai9GQytXRXhWeThMbUFLMHV2L3By?=
=?utf-8?B?LzVQOFMra2dtNHJubkVLcEozN0ZWTU9UeENmbGY0UjdnZHQrZ2R6V0FiZXRJ?=
=?utf-8?B?OXFTYjB6TWNyQzhQYnh4SjdBWVA2dWxTTE4yTldHWFZtblA5UktnMkFTREtR?=
=?utf-8?B?Q0s2NE9jaDRqeHFBNitSVlBRWHlyQ1gwRjVMTkNlZG9MWG1zaGtGbGRqZ29R?=
=?utf-8?B?bTV1VlpPN1JUMjJWUUtuOStsYnBYdFplWUx1bjFHSzVUbFVuZWFNQjhuSTdN?=
=?utf-8?B?NS9YMW9TS0UramxvUEZTMThXL3JHMVArRGxzSnZoZDlmWCtsT3p6SVBESEV6?=
=?utf-8?B?djJzdFFVRTdiZzJ5eVh0eFE5QlhMWjJaczZCUHRKaEJQY0hLRy9pK0pCSWx5?=
=?utf-8?B?bjA0cjRwOVZqWnZTWGVMOHgzWUhxNWFQeFlpb1I5U1NwdFd4N2xEamRzT2Vz?=
=?utf-8?B?eFpqdmdIamFGVXFybmsyNFREcUVXV0x4UFNDUXNybGtqU090SGNkc25NTDVl?=
=?utf-8?B?a1JMcm5ZdU16TEE5WGkremIzZHNDZ3RtN05oTnlsK1k4TW0vYjVhVUpBZ2pN?=
=?utf-8?B?S3puYWNaZUpLWEJCRlhBUlZERlRFZkxPQ1ZoenFReTFHZjBVLzZBSUJmZm5x?=
=?utf-8?B?ZmZCS3FPTy9IZmFtbnh5NWlsTUNSSzRNZ1ZrL2RPdnpERmpjUzVucm9YV0hZ?=
=?utf-8?B?N1dHa3NteGhpUGFFZFFvdVpqY0tia3lFUGFYZUkrNjRGQkpnczNVb0RsdFRq?=
=?utf-8?B?V3BVV0dWR1R0c0lFam5hNDh6eWpTOWlhVGg1SXNYQ1J0ZHBqeFhvZGNCb0k5?=
=?utf-8?B?NGF4TGZ1cHQ0SThrb0p4anJaRzloTWFlWi96YUU1V3BZbkQ2eDg4bFpONkpy?=
=?utf-8?B?N09OcWtxMEZWNldFY29sZXhoUHpHcmJOR1NsaklaeXB0KzYrVmRPSUVaSytY?=
=?utf-8?Q?Qj2h4+ncBxAu+GEVJa/8?=
MIME-Version: 1.0

--_=_swift_v4_1599235292_7fddbc54cfbf1e9b40d7f7974bdfb7a8_=_
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Hola Leonardo Ud quiere recuperar su contrase&ntilde;a, podr&aacu......


-----------------------------------
/END Recibed E-Mail in Outlook (Headers)
-----------------------------------
```

I configured exim via WHM and I am handling the / etc / mailsips and / etc / mailhelo files manually:

/etc/mailip

```
*: 144.217.55.5
update.dominio1.com: 167.114.80.109
web.dominio1.com: 167.114.80.109
dominio1.com: 167.114.80.109
dev.dominio2.com: 167.114.80.110
dominio2.com: 167.114.80.110          <------
```

/etc/mailhelo

```
*: server.myprimaryserver.com
dominio1.com: dominio1.com
web.dominio1.com: dominio1.com
update.dominio1.com: dominio1.com.ar
dominio2.com: dominio2.com             <-----
dev.dominio2.com: dominio2.com
```

So ... I don't understand why exim resolves the address mail.domain2.com to ip .109 instead of .110 ...

I was studying a little exim configuration options ... and I found this:

> For messages from other hosts, **the H and U fields identify the remote**
> **host** and record the RFC 1413 identity of the user that sent the
> message, if one was received. The number given in square brackets is
> the IP address of the sending host. If there is a single,
> unparenthesized host name in the H field, as above, it has been
> verified to correspond to the IP address (see the host_lookup option).
> **If the name is in parentheses**, it was the name quoted by the remote
> host in the SMTP HELO or EHLO command, and has not been verified. If
> verification yields a different name to that given for HELO or EHLO,
> the verified name appears first, followed by the HELO or EHLO name in
> parentheses.
>
> Misconfigured hosts (and mail forgers) sometimes put an IP address,
> with or without brackets, in the HELO or EHLO command, leading to
> entries in the log containing text like these examples:
>
> H=(10.21.32.43) [192.168.8.34] H=([10.21.32.43]) [192.168.8.34] This
> can be confusing. Only the final address in square brackets can be
> relied on.
>
> For locally generated messages (that is, messages not received over
> TCP/IP), the H field is omitted, and the U field contains the login
> name of the caller of Exim.
>
> For all messages, the P field specifies the protocol used to receive
> the message. This is the value that is stored in $received_protocol.
> In the case of incoming SMTP messages, the value indicates whether or
> not any SMTP extensions (ESMTP), encryption, or authentication were
> used. If the SMTP session was encrypted, there is an additional X
> field that records the cipher suite that was used.
>
> The protocol is set to “esmtpsa” or “esmtpa” for messages received
> from hosts that have authenticated themselves using the SMTP AUTH
> command. The first value is used when the SMTP connection was
> encrypted (“secure”). In this case there is an additional item A=
> followed by the name of the authenticator that was used. If an
> authenticated identification was set up by the authenticator’s
> server_set_id option, this is logged too, separated by a colon from
> the authenticator name.
>
> The id field records the existing message id, if present. The size of
> the received message is given by the S field. When the message is
> delivered, headers may be removed or added, so that the size of
> delivered copies of the message may not correspond with this value
> (and indeed may be different to each other).
>
> The log_selector option can be used to request the logging of
> additional data when a message is received. See section 53.15 below.

Fuente: https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-log_files.html#SECID251

PS: If you want to know any other configuration in particular, just ask and I will send you more info.

### Edit 1:

At the request of Anonymous I edit the question to add the DNS resolution using the nslookup and dig commands.
Add the dig command results from my server where I have the problem with exim, and try to query another dns server (8.8.8.8) to be able to compare, I also add the Reverse DNS resolution.
I am changing the ips, if they do tests it will not give them the same results, it is a matter of privacy, if someone wants to commit to investigate more, they could send the real data by private message.

NS LOOKUP:

```
[root@server ~]# nslookup dominio2.com
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   dominio2.com
Address: 167.114.80.110

[root@server ~]# nslookup dominio1.com
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   dominio1.com
Address: 167.114.80.109

[root@server ~]# nslookup www.dominio2.com
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
www.dominio2.com      canonical name = dominio2.com.
Name:   dominio2.com
Address: 167.114.80.110

[root@server ~]# nslookup www.dominio1.com
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
www.dominio1.com canonical name = dominio1.com.
Name:   dominio1.com
Address: 167.114.80.109

[root@server ~]# nslookup 167.114.80.110
110.80.114.167.in-addr.arpa     name = dominio2.com.

Authoritative answers can be found from:
114.167.in-addr.arpa    nameserver = dns10.ovh.ca.
114.167.in-addr.arpa    nameserver = ns10.ovh.ca.

[root@server ~]# nslookup 167.114.80.109
129.84.114.167.in-addr.arpa     name = dominio1.com.

Authoritative answers can be found from:
114.167.in-addr.arpa    nameserver = ns10.ovh.ca.
114.167.in-addr.arpa    nameserver = dns10.ovh.ca.
```

DIG:

```
[root@server ~]# dig dominio2.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-9.P2.el7 <<>> dominio2.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 22969
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 9

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;dominio2.com.                        IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
dominio2.com.         8297    IN      A       167.114.80.110

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
com.ar.                 12333   IN      NS      a.dns.ar.
com.ar.                 12333   IN      NS      c.dns.ar.
com.ar.                 12333   IN      NS      e.dns.ar.
com.ar.                 12333   IN      NS      b.dns.ar.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
a.dns.ar.               85847   IN      A       200.108.145.50
b.dns.ar.               85847   IN      A       200.108.147.50
c.dns.ar.               85847   IN      A       200.108.148.50
e.dns.ar.               85847   IN      A       170.238.66.50
a.dns.ar.               12333   IN      AAAA    2801:140::10
b.dns.ar.               127182  IN      AAAA    2801:140:11::50
c.dns.ar.               10170   IN      AAAA    2801:140:10::10
e.dns.ar.               10170   IN      AAAA    2801:140:eeee::50

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Sep 07 08:45:34 -03 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 303




[root@server ~]# dig www.dominio2.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-9.P2.el7 <<>> www.dominio2.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 37005
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 9

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.dominio2.com.            IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.dominio2.com.     11245   IN      CNAME   dominio2.com.
dominio2.com.         8233    IN      A       167.114.80.110

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
com.ar.                 12269   IN      NS      b.dns.ar.
com.ar.                 12269   IN      NS      a.dns.ar.
com.ar.                 12269   IN      NS      c.dns.ar.
com.ar.                 12269   IN      NS      e.dns.ar.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
a.dns.ar.               85783   IN      A       200.108.145.50
b.dns.ar.               85783   IN      A       200.108.147.50
c.dns.ar.               85783   IN      A       200.108.148.50
e.dns.ar.               85783   IN      A       170.238.66.50
a.dns.ar.               12269   IN      AAAA    2801:140::10
b.dns.ar.               127118  IN      AAAA    2801:140:11::50
c.dns.ar.               10106   IN      AAAA    2801:140:10::10
e.dns.ar.               10106   IN      AAAA    2801:140:eeee::50

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Sep 07 08:46:38 -03 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 321




[root@server ~]# dig @8.8.8.8 dominio2.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-9.P2.el7 <<>> @8.8.8.8 dominio2.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 29665
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;dominio2.com.                        IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
dominio2.com.         14399   IN      A       167.114.80.110

;; Query time: 24 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Mon Sep 07 08:47:42 -03 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 59





[root@server ~]# dig @8.8.8.8 www.dominio2.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-9.P2.el7 <<>> @8.8.8.8 www.dominio2.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 60583
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.dominio2.com.            IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.dominio2.com.     14399   IN      CNAME   dominio2.com.
dominio2.com.         14399   IN      A       167.114.80.110

;; Query time: 50 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Mon Sep 07 08:48:21 -03 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 77





[root@server ~]# dig 167.114.80.110

; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-9.P2.el7 <<>> 167.114.80.110
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 20428
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;167.114.80.110.                        IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.                       10800   IN      SOA     a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2020090700 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 8 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Sep 07 08:49:46 -03 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 118




[root@server ~]# dig @8.8.8.8 167.114.80.110

; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-9.P2.el7 <<>> @8.8.8.8 167.114.80.110
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 27434
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;167.114.80.110.                        IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.                       86376   IN      SOA     a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2020090700 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Mon Sep 07 08:50:15 -03 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 118




[root@server ~]# dig +answer -x 167.114.80.110

; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-9.P2.el7 <<>> +answer -x 167.114.80.110
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 25781
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;130.84.114.167.in-addr.arpa.   IN      PTR

;; ANSWER SECTION:
130.84.114.167.in-addr.arpa. 78762 IN   PTR     dominio2.com.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
114.167.in-addr.arpa.   78762   IN      NS      dns10.ovh.ca.
114.167.in-addr.arpa.   78762   IN      NS      ns10.ovh.ca.

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Sep 07 08:58:36 -03 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 129
```

---

### EDIT 2:

Added PTR for .129 (dominio1.com)

```
[root@server ~]# dig -x 167.114.80.109

; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-9.P2.el7 <<>> -x 167.114.80.109
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 56187
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 3

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;109.80.114.167.in-addr.arpa.   IN      PTR

;; ANSWER SECTION:
109.80.114.167.in-addr.arpa. 2897 IN    PTR     dominio1.com.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
114.167.in-addr.arpa.   77211   IN      NS      dns10.ovh.ca.
114.167.in-addr.arpa.   77211   IN      NS      ns10.ovh.ca.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
dns10.ovh.ca.           2258    IN      A       192.99.60.247
ns10.ovh.ca.            2258    IN      A       167.114.154.30

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Wed Sep 09 09:28:15 -03 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 166
```

Comment: Are you sure that the problem lies with Exim ? I would check the DNS configuration for your domains, check if you have PTR records set up for your IP addresses, review the IP addresses in your DNS configuration and also try to resolve the domain names from the server where Exim runs. Use dig or nslookup from the command line for example. Also verify you don't have stale entries in your hosts file.

Comment: We don't handle questions about cPanel systems here. You should seek help from cPanel support.

Comment: Hi Anonimous, no ... I'm not sure it's exim who is "lying". Add the information you request, under the section "edit 1". **I would suspect that there is some kind of configuration error in how exim results the "IP" to which the "HOST" belongs (mail.domain2.com) and for some reason as you decide, take it wrong.** As soon as I can I will review the virtualhost files in detail. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry @Michael Hampton, I didn't know, do what you have to do, delete it, close it, etc. I'm going to post to the cpanel forum, to see if they really want to help out there! PS: Thanks Anonimous! You do take a risk by collaborating and I appreciate it! xD

Comment: Have you checked the PTR for 167.114.80.109 eg: `dig -x 167.114.80.109`

Comment: Hi @Anonymous, yes and I add the result of dig -x to ip .109 as "edit 2:" in the post, but I don't see anything strange. any other idea?